# Clear next nested select tags if previous is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I've got a following problem - I got several nested select inputs which are dependent on each other. And I'm trying to have a following effect - If I select the "Choose" option than all of following select tags will be cleared

**HTML:**

```
<fieldset>
            <legend>Dwelling</legend>
            <p> 
                <span>Continet:</span> <select class="dwelling" name="continent" id="continent" onchange="getplaces(this.value,'country',this);"></select>
            </p>
            <p>
                <span>Country:</span> <select class="dwelling" name="country" id="country" onchange="getplaces(this.value,'province',this);"></select>
            </p>
            <p>
                <span>State / Provice:</span> <select class="dwelling" name="province" id="province" onchange="getplaces(this.value,'region',this);"></select>
            </p>
            <p>
                <span>County / Region:</span> <select class="dwelling" name="region" id="region" onchange="getplaces(this.value,'city',this);"></select>
            </p>
            <p>
                <span>City:</span> <select class="dwelling" name="city" id="city"></select>
            </p>
</fieldset>
```

**JavaScript:**

I've tried that but it's not working and I think that I have run out of ideas how to manage that to work.

```
function getplaces(val,src,t)
{   
    if(val!= "choose"){
        //fetching dependent records + one option on top with "choose" value    
    }else{
        $(t).closest('fieldset').nextAll(".dwelling").html("");
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Thanks for all fast responses but maybe I've formulated the question wrong. I want to clear out only next select tags after the one with "choose" options so all of which are located before it will remain unaffected.

Comment: Why nextall? it only selects siblings, your selects are all descendants of the fieldset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to target all the `select` elements in next `p` elements

```
function getplaces(val, src, t) {
    if (val != "choose") {
        //fetching dependent records + one option on top with "choose" value    
    } else {
        $(t).closest('p').nextAll().find('select.dwelling').empty();
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9qVYB/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing its just the options you want removed from the dropdown.

```
$(t).closest('fieldset').find(".dwelling option").remove();
```